# where string literals will be stored

Tags: c++, string

I use visual studio 2017

```
int main()
{
    std::string a = "hello";
    std::cout << &a;  
    a[1] = 'r';
    std::cout << &a;  gives same address as above 
    std::cin.get();
}
```

when i hover the mouse pointer over "hello".

It shows const char[6]. So "hello" is stored in read only memory.

then how come it is possible to change the value in it.

[screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yDILJ.png)

Comment: `a` isn't a string literal. It's a `std::string` that was constructed using a string literal, but it has its own copy of the data, possibly on the heap. Try `"hello"[1] = 'r';` and you'll almost certainly get a crash.

Comment: Where do you change the value in `"hello"`? I can only see you changing `a`.

Comment: `42` is an integer constant. `int a = 42; std::cin >> a;` modifies the variable `a`; that does not mean it is possible to change the value of integer constants.

Comment: then a stores the address of "hello"(0x0053fcf0 "hello"). I looked into 0x0053fcf0. It has "hello". After changing the value ,l looked into that same memory.But with "hrllo"

Comment: This is the reason why we have `std::string_view` (to avoid the copy that std::string does)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> where string literals will be stored

String literals have static storage duration.

> then how come it is possible to change the value in it.

You didn't change the string literal (which is something that cannot be done in C++).

You've created an object of type `std::string`. `std::string` contains a (potentially) dynamically allocated buffer. You've copied the string literal into that dynamic buffer, and you're modifying the copy of the string literal.

> But with "hrllo".It should allocate new memory for "hrllo" right? and make a to point to new location?

No. Modifying characters of a `std::string` will not cause reallocation. Inserting characters however may *potentially* cause reallocation.

Comment: then a stores the address of "hello"(0x0053fcf0 "hello"). I looked into 0x0053fcf0. It has "hello". After changing the value ,l looked into that same memory.But with "hrllo".It should allocate new memory for "hrllo" right? and make a to point to new location?

Comment: then it may possible that "hello" still may be present somewhere?

Comment: please explain the overflow of what is happening

Comment: @bubeshp The string literal is still present. I don't understand what you refer to by "overflow."

Comment: location of "hello" is 0x0053fcf0. It is const char.So we cannot change the value in that location.But after i changed the value. Location of "hrllo" is also 0x0053fcf0. how is that possible?

Comment: @bubeshp I suspect that your assumption that `It is const char` is incorrect.

Comment: look at the screen shot in question

Comment: @bubeshp that screen shot shows the type of the string literal. That type has nothing to do with what is inside `std::string`.

Answer (score 1):

The `std::string` makes a copy of "hello" and you didn't make the `std::string` itself const.

Comment: then a stores the address of "hello"(0x0053fcf0 "hello"). I looked into 0x0053fcf0. It has "hello". After changing the value ,l looked into that same memory.But with "hrllo".It should allocate new memory for "hrllo" right? and make a to point to new location?

Answer (score 1):

The literal `"hello"` sits in read-only memory of the executable, which is there even before the program runs. The variable `a`is constructed from the literal through:

```
string::string(const char*)
```

(actually [std::basic_string](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string))

This constructor copies the characters from the literal to the newly created object. If the string is short, then the characters may be copied directly to the memory of the object. Otherwise, a new memory area is allocated, the characters are copied there, and the object points to the new block.

Never does the new object store a pointer to the original literal.

## edit

The lines

```
std::cout << &a;
```

Takes the address of the object (named `a`) of type `std::basic_string<char>`. This object sits on the stack, and is created and destroyed inside `int main()`. The object does not move, so the pointer is constant and does not change when the string changes. This is the same as the `this` pointer inside the methods of the `std::basic_string<char>` of this object.

Comment: then a stores the address of "hello"(0x0053fcf0 "hello"). I looked into 0x0053fcf0. It has "hello". After changing the value ,l looked into that same memory.But with "hrllo".It should allocate new memory for "hrllo" right? and make a to point to new location?

Comment: @bubeshp `a` internally stores the address of a copy of `"hello"`. It does not just point to a constant.

Comment: @bubeshp No, `a` copies the characters pointed by `a`. It may store it in-place (short string optimization) or allocate a new memory block, copy the string there, and put the new pointer into `a`

Comment: then it may possible that "hello" still may be present somewhere?

Comment: please explain me the overflow of whats happening of what is happening

Comment: @bubeshp Yes, unless this is a DLL/shared library (Which can be unloaded), it is most likely still present. I am not sure if the standard forbids optimizations that might reuse the memory of the literal.

Comment: @bubeshp I have added an explanation of `cout<<&a` to the answer